# Css transition fails after setting height to zero

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have expand and collapse animations on a div in an article element.

Based on this fiddle code: [csstransitions demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ns8yZ/6/)

When the div box is expanded ("div.expandable") I don't want to leave the height hardcoded (locked) to a specific value, and therefore I reset it by removing the height value: `el.css("height", "");` when the animation is complete.

I restore the height (back to say 136px) before setting it again to "0" for the collapse/close animation.
There is no collapsing animation back to `height: 0` after having reset it. But if I leave the height to 136px after the expand animation then the collapse animation works fine.

If you comment out `el.css("height", "");` then the animation works fine.

Does the `height` have to always be set to a specific value? If so then there is no height responsiveness when resizing the browser width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set max-height (with a height, your text will never use) instead of height:

JS

```
$(".preface").click(function(){
    var el = $(this).parent().find(".expandable");
    el.toggleClass("expanded");
});
```

CSS

```
.expandable {
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
}

.expanded {
    max-height: 2000px;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrona/ns8yZ/8/) with your updated code.

.expandable doesn't need `style="height: 0"` anymore. Unfortunately this solution messes up your transition-duration, as it calculates the time needed for max-height, not height.

Comment: Indeed. But the animation does not look good. I will experiment with using max-height for the collapse animation only.

Answer (score 1):

Transitioning heights/widths to/from auto in CSS is tricky, which is essentially what you're doing when you remove the height value. There is a trick to get around that which might help you out: it involves cloning the element, setting the height and width to auto, measuring the height of the duplicate element, and then removing it, allowing you to have flexible heights/widths and still animating them. See http://darcyclarke.me/development/fix-jquerys-animate-to-allow-auto-values-2/ for an example.

Comment: I have a jQuery fallback that works fine. I want csstransitions to be the primary solution, mostly becuase of hardware acceleration.

Comment: Makes sense, HW acceleration is always good to go for if you can. In that case, chrona's answer will be what you're looking for. Getting the transition duration right is tricky, though, especially if your content is very variable in size.